# How to set ngStyle to a default value in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ng-style

Here is a part of my html:

```
<div class="container">
```

And here is the related CSS part:

```
.container{
width:100%;
height: 45px;}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
.container{
height:60px;}
```

Now I want to bind the style of this div to a property by ngStyle. I have a property in app.component.ts called `isShrinked`, and when `isShrinked===true`,  I would like the height of the div to be 10px, otherwise the height would be the default value set by the css style of `container` class.

Now I read the Angular documentation about [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle#ngStyle) but I cannot find the correct syntax to achieve this. The closest I can do is by adding something like`[ngStyle]="{'height': isShrinked?'10px':''}"` But this obviously does not work as I would have to give a value to the right side in this ternary expression, which is not what I intend to do.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following syntaxes should work:

```
[ngStyle]="isShrinked ? { 'height': '10px' } : {}"
[ngStyle]="isShrinked ? { 'height': '10px' } : null"
```

If only one style attribute is to be set, the same result can be obtained with this specific style binding:

```
[style.height.px]="isShrinked ? 10 : null"
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a6cdhm) for a demo.